# adding records to a dataset asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

Whene i try to add a record to the dataset the previous one crush,i have a form and I add data to a dataset after every click on the button1 and every time i find my last record only
 here is my code

---

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
    {

        private DataTable dt=new DataTable("manager");
        private DataSet data_set=new DataSet("Test");
        private static int _stagiaireid = 0;
        public static int StagiaireID { get { return _stagiaireid++; } }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //dt = new DataTable("manager");

            dt.Columns.Add("id ", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("electro ", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("sn", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("date ", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("email", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("marque ", typeof(string));
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Siera", "Siera"));
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("AB","AB"));
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("CD","CD"));
            data_set.Tables.Add(dt);
           GridView1.DataSource = data_set.Tables["manager"];


        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String electro = TextBox1.Text;
            String sn = TextBox2.Text;
            String date = TextBox3.Text;
            String email = TextBox4.Text;
            String marque = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() ;
            if (aide.nom_pre(email)==true)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Email Juste";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Email Faux";
                return;
            }
            data_set.Tables["manager"].Rows.Add(StagiaireID, electro, sn, date, email, marque);
           // dt.Rows.Add(StagiaireID,electro, sn, date, email, marque);
            GridView1.DataBind();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you will get only the last record because you are creating and populating the `DataSet` and the `DataTable` in every postback and you didn't store the `DataSet` in a session state also you didn't bind the `GridView`
change your code to:

```
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable("manager");
    private DataSet data_set = new DataSet("Test");
    private static int _stagiaireid = 0;
    public static int StagiaireID { get { return _stagiaireid++; } }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("id ", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("electro ", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("sn", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("date ", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("email", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("marque ", typeof(string));
            data_set.Tables.Add(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = data_set.Tables["manager"];

            this.ViewState["ds"] = data_set;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            data_set = (DataSet)ViewState["ds"];
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String electro = TextBox1.Text;
        String sn = TextBox2.Text;
        String date = TextBox3.Text;
        String email = TextBox4.Text;
        String marque = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (aide.nom_pre(email) == true)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Email Juste";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Email Faux";
            return;
        }

        data_set.Tables["manager"].Rows.Add(StagiaireID, electro, sn, date, email, marque);       
        GridView1.DataSource = data_set.Tables["manager"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        this.ViewState["ds"] = data_set;
    }
```

It's good to understand [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not persisting the dataset across the post backs . so keep your dataset in  session .  refer about state management mechanism in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Before binding data table to grid view, call the `AcceptChanges()` method on the data table in which you have added the rows, then again assign the `DataSource` to grid view with this table.

```
data_set.Tables["manager"].Rows.Add(StagiaireID, electro, sn, date, email, marque);
data_set.Tables["manager"].AcceptChanges();
GridView1.DataSource = data_set.Tables["manager"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```